# vudeo information ::AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, video

I want to get some information like number of frame, fps ,... from binary video file but i get error

```
def GetVideoInformation_binary(vid_binary): #input=binary of video 

    num_frame = int(vid_binary.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    fps    = vid_binary.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
```

error is

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

How can convert binary video file to videocapture object to skip this error?

Comment: Error is very straight forward, `vid_binary` is a string, and string has no  `get` method. Solution isn't possible if you don't put details about the library you are using.

Comment: I use cv2 libariry.

Comment: From where you are getting this `vid_binary`?  I haven't used cv2 before, but it seems from the doc that you can get videocapture object straight from the filename.

Comment: vid_binary is binary of video that get from internet or other..

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `get()` on a string, which is wrong. It is an attribute of  `VideoCapture` , so you need to create a videoCapture object from your string data.

So, I suggest you to make a file with `vid_binary` content. And, then make a `VideoCapture` object from this file. Like below:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("filename.ext")
```

Then call your methods on it.

```
num_frame = int(cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
fps = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
```

It should work fine now.

Comment: wfile = open('binary.mp4', 'wb')

    for b in vid_binary:
        wfile.write(b)
    wfile.close()
    cap= cv2.VideoCapture('binary.mp4')   i converted binary file to .mp4 and use VideoCapture .. but i search for a solution without write file ... i want spead code

Comment: Okay, so you already have a file? right? Then you can feed the existing file, no new file is needed.

Comment: Just do `cap= cv2.VideoCapture('binary.mp4')`, it should work. No need to read first and then write back to file.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add an attribute "get" to skip this error. It's written right in front of you.

Comment: how? the input is binary but this function nead videocaptute object as input